# Jacobson radical of $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

> Let $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ be the ring of integers localized at a prime ideal $(p)$. What is its Jacobson radical, i.e., the intersection of all its maximal ideals?

Theorem: Let $x\in R$. Then $x$ lies in the Jacobson radical iff $1 - x y$ is a unit for all $y\in R$.

Comment: It is a local ring, so it has just one maximal ideal, which of course it's the Jacobson radical.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a field, so it has only trivial ideal.

Comment: See herehttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_radical

Comment: @Nirdonkey The OP is talking about the localization at a prime ideal, which is definitely not a field (unless the prime ideal is $(0)$).

Comment: @Nirkondey $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ mean different things.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thinked it was $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: @egreg, local ring is a new concept to me, I will look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $P=\left\{\dfrac{ap}{b}:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}, b\notin(p)\right\}$ and prove it is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$. Are there other maximal ideals?

Answer (score 1):

What is its only maximal ideal? Hint: Try thinking about which elements are not invertible.